# Primary key requirement in raw SQL complicates the query in Django

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-orm

To get max value from a simple table of values, I can write the following query in Django:

```
MyTable.objects.aggregate(Max('value'))
```

The SQL generated is : `'SELECT MAX("mytable"."value") AS "value__max" FROM "mytable"'`

Now if I write the same SQL using the raw query manager:

```
1. MyTable.objects.raw('SELECT max(value) FROM mytable')
```

Django throws an error `InvalidQuery: Raw query must include the primary key`. This is also mentioned in Django docs: "There is only one field that you can’t leave out - the primary key field". So after adding the `id` field, I need `GROUP BY` as well. The new query becomes:

```
2. MyTable.objects.raw('SELECT id, max(value) FROM mytable GROUP BY id')
```

This doesn't give me a single max value anymore because I'm forced to use `GROUP BY id`. Now I need to add an `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` statement to get the expected answer for an otherwise simple SQL statement that work.

```
3. MyTable.objects.raw('SELECT id, max(value) AS mv FROM mytable GROUP BY id ORDER BY mv DESC LIMIT 1')
```

Is there a way simplify the above query i.e. not use ORDER/LIMIT/GROUP BY (FWIW, using PosgreSQL)?

**Update:**

Here's a hack that'll work. I alias the max value as `id` to make Django happy. Is there any issue here?

```
MyTable.objects.raw('SELECT max(value) AS id FROM mytable')
```

**Update 2:**

Here's the query plan for the simple SQL (1) vs the complicated final one (3):

```
"Aggregate  (cost=5.25..5.26 rows=1 width=2) (actual time=0.155..0.155 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..4.60 rows=260 width=2) (actual time=0.018..0.067 rows=260 loops=1)"
"Total runtime: 0.222 ms"
```

```
"Limit  (cost=9.80..9.80 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.548..0.548 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=9.80..10.45 rows=260 width=6) (actual time=0.545..0.545 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: (max(value))"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB"
"        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=5.90..8.50 rows=260 width=6) (actual time=0.328..0.432 rows=260 loops=1)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..4.60 rows=260 width=6) (actual time=0.018..0.069 rows=260 loops=1)"
"Total runtime: 0.638 ms"
```

**P.S.** The actual query is more complicated (somewhat related to this answer : https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/86404/52114)

Comment: `GROUP BY <primary-key>` (without any other tables joined) defeats the purpose of aggregated values (i.e. in your example `max(value)` will select max from only 1 value) -- `SELECT max(value) FROM mytable GROUP BY id LIMIT 1` is not the same as `SELECT max(value) FROM mytable`

Comment: You missed the `ORDER BY` clause. 1) & 3) should give the same results if there's a single max value. If there's more than 1, you need to add id or something to make the order predictable.

Comment: order does not matter (it only makes your queries predictable); 1) & 3) shouldn't give you the same results generally, only in special cases: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ceb1d/2 -- you can use `ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1` too to find the max value, but in this case you don't need aggregation at all.

Comment: In your fiddle, the 2nd & 3rd queries are obviously wrong. The 2nd query above in my question is an intermediate. Also not sure why you are adding another 'mv' column. It's alias for max(value) (see above). The question I'm asking is how to use the max(value) in raw query without complicating it by adding `id` and `GROUP/LIMIT/ORDER` clause while still using the raw query manager. I know there are many ways to get the max value, but I want to use the aggregation function because the actual query uses `max` in a more complicated scenario (see here http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/86404/52114).

Comment: Got it now (I thought mv is a column, my bad). That way too using `max()` is unnecessary, just select `value`: the max is selected through sorting -- about the query plans: PostgreSQL's query optimisations can depend on a lot of things. If you can, post your whole query (formatted). But in general I'm agree with @ClodoaldoNeto 's comment on @catavaran 's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560912/primary-key-requirement-in-raw-sql-complicates-the-query-in-django?noredirect=1#comment43548905_27561231

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use [custom SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) instead of `Manager.raw()` method:

```
from django.db import connection

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT max(value) FROM mytable')
max_value = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: I think that's the route I might end up taking. I'm experimenting with some workarounds but an `explain analyze` shows that the query is unnecessarily being complicated due to `id` requirement.

Comment: @user4150760 Trying to control the ORM behaviour adds another layer of complexity and unpredictability that completely defeats the ORM purpose.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Could you elaborate on `Trying to control the ORM behaviour`? Isn't raw SQL bypassing ORM?

Comment: @user4150760 As you experienced yourself `Manager.raw()` does not completely bypass the ORM. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/

Comment: Is there a way to get django model instances after excuting the custom SQL?

Answer (score 8):

U can use

```
ModelName.objects.raw('SELECT 1 as id , max(value) FROM mytable')
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had same issue, @Tinashe Robert's not working for me. May I share my solution(Python 3.7.7, Django 3.0.5):

PS: Yes, @catavaran's answer is native Python, but if one really want to use RAW?

- Firstly, primary_key needs to be appointed to one column in MySQL DB field, i.e.:

```
 class MyTable(model.Model):
     id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     value = models.IntegerField(10)
     ...
```

with API shell:

```
>>> MyTable.objects.raw('SELECT id, max(value) as mx from MyTable')[0].mx
```

or simpler solution:

```
>>> from django.db.models import Max
>>> MyTable.objects.all().aggregate(Max('value'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
select id, value from mytable order by value desc limit 1
```

Comment: You mean `order by value desc`

Comment: After incorporating changes suggested by @ClodoaldoNeto, the explain analyze still shows that it isn't any simpler.

Comment: @user4150760, max is an aggregate function. It is logically simpler to use order by and take the first. Especially if you have an index on the given column

Comment: My observation was given as a comment. The op wants to get the id of the maximum value, which is calculated by the code in my answer, therefore my answer is a solution. A better solution than the op initially wanted to achieve. Also, the op has a solution, but wanted to simplify it. His observation here is not about my answer being wrongly placed, thus he acknowledged it is an answer. His observation was that the explain analyze did not show this to be simpler.