# Django PostGIS spatial query

Tags: django, python-3.x, geodjango

I'm trying to do a spatial query in Django to a PostGIS database, but I've not been able to do it. I've try it with raw querys a with this [GIS QuerySet API Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#std:fieldlookup-within.). I dont know what I'm doing wrong.

this is my modeles.py file:

```
class RayosTotal(models.Model):
    ka = models.FloatField(db_column='kA', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    tiempo = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Tiempo',primary_key=True, blank=True, null=False)  # Field name made lowercase.
    geom = models.PointField(blank=True, null=True)

        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'Rayos_total'
            unique_together = (('lat', 'lng', 'tiempo'),)

class Departamentos(models.Model):
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(blank=True, null=True)
    cod_dane = models.IntegerField(db_column='COD_DANE',primary_key=True, blank=True, null=False)
    nom_dpto = models.CharField(db_column='NOM_DPTO', max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'departamentos'
```

and this is my views.py

```
def join1(request):     
    points = serialize('geojson',RayosTotal.objects.all())
    x=serialize('geojson',Departamentos.objects.filter(geom__contains=points))    
    return HttpResponse(x,content_type='json')
    #with join1 I get this message: Couldn't create spatial object from lookup value

def join2(request):
    x=RayosTotal.objects.raw("""SELECT "Rayos_total".geom AS geom
FROM "public"."Rayos_total"
INNER JOIN "public"."departamentos" ON ST_Within("Rayos_total".geom, "departamentos".geom)
WHERE "departamentos"."NOM_DPTO" = 'CHOCO'""")
    return HttpResponse(x,content_type='json')
    #with join2 I get this message: Raw query must include the primary key
```

any ideas ? thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I solve this problem with the help of   [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560912/primary-key-requirement-in-raw-sql-complicates-the-query-in-django) 
this is the final code:

```
from django.db import connection

def join(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT "Rayos_total"."Fecha" AS geom,
        "departamentos"."NOM_DPTO" as dpto
FROM "public"."Rayos_total"
INNER JOIN "public"."departamentos" ON ST_Within("Rayos_total".geom, "departamentos".geom)
WHERE "departamentos"."COLOMBIA" = '57'
AND "Tiempo" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '1 DAYS' AND NOW()""")
    data = cursor
    return HttpResponse(data,content_type='json')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be using the Point objects in your query, since you are serializing the data before querying.

This may work:

```py
def join1(request):     
    # get list of points
    points = [r.geom for r in RayosTotal.objects.filter(geom__isnull=False)]
    x=serialize('geojson',Departamentos.objects.filter(geom__contains=points))    
    return HttpResponse(x,content_type='json')
```

Comment: I don't know if this doesn't work for large data, since I'm getting this message: Tuple too long for lookup contains. and when I limit points[0:1] seems to work and fails at points[0:3]

Comment: Could be that the `geom` field allows _null_ and I wasn't filtering out invalid values.  I added a filter to the answer.

Comment: I keep getting the same message, also you are missing the __in__ in the list comprehension. And thank you, I already solve this issue, you can see my answer.